# adding external SQLite database to android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a SQLite database with "SQLite Expert" and it's name is "dbtest".
I copied it to assets folder,when i run the program it shows this dialog:
[image]

And this is the method for copying database to data folder:

```
public final String path="data/data/sqlitedatabaseexample.example.ahmad.sqlitedatabaseexample/databases";
    public final String Name ="dbtest";
       public void copydatabase() throws IOException      // method for copy database from assets folder to program's data folder
        {
            OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(path+Name);   //destination address
            byte [] buffer = new byte [1024];
            int length;

            InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open("dbtest");  // file name that is in Assets folder
            while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0)
            {
                myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
            }
            myinput.close();
            myoutput.flush();
            myoutput.close();

        }
```

What I should to do ?(I dont want to add a format to dbtest)

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem you are asking for?

Comment: If i select text in dialog, it takes errors

Comment: In Android Studio dialog? Report a bug to Google / Jetbrains.

Comment: Use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not true to import an external database to android programs.we can create it in projects by two classes.